Boost-Mysql error when shared_ptr is created for connection object
I have the following code which encompasses a boost::mysql connection using a shared_ptr. I want to keep the connection object for the duration of the application's runtime. I want the application to then close the connection on the end of the runtime. However, I get an access violation when debugging the process.
class DatabaseProcess : public MainframeComponent
{
public:
    // MainframeComponent dispatch module type is set to Main because DatabaseProcess doesn't run on its own thread.
    DatabaseProcess(boost::asio::io_context &io_context) : _io_context(io_context), MainframeComponent(Horizon::System::RUNTIME_DATABASE) { }
    ~DatabaseProcess() 
    { 
        // Close connection object.
        if (_connection != nullptr) {
            _connection->close();
            _connection.reset();
        }

    }
    void initialize(int segment_number = 1) override { HLog(error) << "Database not configured"; }
    void initialize(int segment_number, std::string host, int port, std::string user, std::string pass, std::string database)
    {
        try {
            boost::asio::ssl::context ssl_ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tls_client);
            _connection = std::make_shared<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection>(_io_context.get_executor(), ssl_ctx);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(_io_context.get_executor());
            auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(host, std::to_string(port));
            boost::mysql::handshake_params params(user, pass, database);
            _connection->connect(*endpoints.begin(), params);
        } catch (boost::mysql::error_with_diagnostics &error) {
            HLog(error) << error.what();
        }

        bool value = _is_initialized;
        _is_initialized.compare_exchange_strong(value, true);
    }

    void finalize(int segment_number = 1) override 
    {
        bool value = _is_initialized;
        _is_initialized.compare_exchange_strong(value, false);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> get_connection() { return _connection; }

    bool is_initialized() { return _is_initialized.load(); }
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> _connection{nullptr};
    boost::asio::io_context &_io_context;
    std::atomic<bool> _is_initialized;
};

Debug output:

Running 1 test case...

*** No errors detected
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA63663FAA (ntdll.dll) in ZoneSystemTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000024.
The program '[27192] ZoneSystemTest.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The lines responsible significantly are -
_connection = std::make_shared<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection>(_io_context.get_executor(), ssl_ctx);


When commented, the error goes away. Is it because we can't create a resource in memory of the connection object?

This is because of a bug in the not shown code.

The lifetimes of objects are not guarded well.

the _io_context member is initialized AFTER the base class, you want to fix the order of the initializers to reflect this

the ssl_ctx is destructed before the end of initialize. It probably needs to be a member object

you probably want to use all the resolver endpoints in the connection attempt:
     boost::asio::connect(_connection->stream().next_layer(), endpoints);


most importantly, the lifetime of the io_context object is not shown, but needs to be guarded.


Everything could be greatly simplified by avoiding references, two-step initialization and dynamic allocation.
Some Fixes
Some of the above fixed:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/mysql.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
#define HLog(level) (std::osyncstream(std::cout) << "\n[" #level "] ")

namespace Horizon::System {
    enum ModuleType {
        RUNTIME_DATABASE,
        RUNTIME_FILESYSTEM,
        RUNTIME_NETWORK,
        RUNTIME_PROCESS,
        RUNTIME_THREAD,
        RUNTIME_TIMER,
        RUNTIME_USER
    };
}

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct MainframeComponent {
    MainframeComponent(Horizon::System::ModuleType module_type) : _module_type(module_type) {}

    virtual ~MainframeComponent()                   = default;
    virtual void initialize(int segment_number = 1) = 0;
    virtual void finalize(int segment_number = 1)   = 0;

    Horizon::System::ModuleType get_module_type() { return _module_type; }

  protected:
    Horizon::System::ModuleType _module_type;
};

class DatabaseProcess : public MainframeComponent {
  public:
    // MainframeComponent dispatch module type is set to Main because DatabaseProcess doesn't run on its own
    // thread.
    DatabaseProcess(asio::io_context& io_context)
        : MainframeComponent(Horizon::System::RUNTIME_DATABASE)
        , _io_context(io_context) {}

    ~DatabaseProcess() {
        // Close connection object.
        if (_connection != nullptr) {
            _connection->close();
            _connection.reset();
        }
    }

    void initialize(int /*segment_number*/ = 1) override { HLog(error) << "Database not configured"; }
    void initialize(int /*segment_number*/, std::string host, int port, std::string user, std::string pass,
                    std::string database) {
        try {
            _connection =
                std::make_shared<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection>(_io_context.get_executor(), ssl_ctx);
            tcp::resolver                  resolver(_io_context.get_executor());
            auto                           endpoints = resolver.resolve(host, std::to_string(port));
            boost::mysql::handshake_params params(user, pass, database);
            // asio::connect(_connection->stream().next_layer(), endpoints);
            _connection->connect(*endpoints.begin(), params);
        } catch (boost::mysql::error_with_diagnostics& error) {
            HLog(error) << error.what();
        }

        bool value = _is_initialized;
        _is_initialized.compare_exchange_strong(value, true);
    }

    void finalize(int /*segment_number*/ = 1) override {
        bool value = _is_initialized;
        _is_initialized.compare_exchange_strong(value, false);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> get_connection() { return _connection; }

    bool is_initialized() { return _is_initialized.load(); }

  protected:
    asio::io_context&                                 _io_context;
    ssl::context                                      ssl_ctx{ssl::context::tls_client};
    std::shared_ptr<boost::mysql::tcp_ssl_connection> _connection{nullptr};
    std::atomic<bool>                                 _is_initialized;
};

int main() {
    //
    asio::io_context ioc;
    DatabaseProcess p(ioc);

    p.initialize(1, "localhost", 3306, "root", "root", "test");
}


The io_context lifetime is simple - in a parent class which creates the DatabaseProcess class and has io_context as the member. I'm using the same io_context for multiple io/related work in my program.

So, at least fix the ssl context. Next, enable sanitizers to see what code triggers any remaining problem

I've made a shared object from ssl::context and made it a member variable, it still has the same error.

Why would "making it a shared object" fix anything? Maybe you mean something else than you say

As a member variable, the lifetime should exceed that of the initialize method

I've also changed the order of initializers, does this really matter? There is no change in the result.

It might matter - the full code isn't shown - it's just good to be aware of the order of member construction/destruction. Anyways: I'd simplify the other way: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b11e3ee2c09ac533, live demo: https://imgur.com/a/fxXH13y If you still experience issues, they are caused elsewhere, and you need to debug e.g. using sanitizers

The io_context belonged to a class which was the child of the class that holds the DatabaseProcess. So the answer was to change the io_context to be a member of that class and making sure that the destruction of DatabaseProcess occurs before the destruction of that class.

Nice! Glad you were able to find it. It's not completely clear what "belong to" and "the child of [the] class" mean, but assuming you meant ownership (via class membership) and a class derived from DatabaseProcess then in fact the initialization order was ultimately the thing that mattered most (just not in the class shown, but same principle). I'm glad I mentioned it. Also, enable warnings on your compiler!

The io_context belonged to a class which was the child of the class that holds the DatabaseProcess. So the answer was to change the io_context to be a member of that class and making sure that the destruction of DatabaseProcess occurs before the destruction of that class.
